# How to set mailbox AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom list programmatically using C#

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect programmatically in C# to Exchange 2007 server via a Powershell runspace to AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom list of the mailbox (Room mailbox/resource mailbox) .
The code is executing without any error, but the user is not getting added to the list.

Here is my code

```
RunspaceConfiguration rc = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException snapEx = null;
PSSnapInInfo info = rc.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapEx);
Runspace r = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rc);
r.Open();
RunspaceInvoke ri = new RunspaceInvoke(r);

string str = "Set-Mailbox -Identity '" 
    + MeetingRoomName
    + "' -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom ((Get-Mailbox -identity '" 
    + MeetingRoomName 
    + "').AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom + " 
    + strUser 
    + ")";

ICollection<PSObject> results = ri.Invoke(str);
```

Could someone please look at my code and let me know how I would go about fixing it so that the Set-Mailbox command runs successfully, and user name should get added to AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom list of the MeetingRoom(Mailbox) in exchange server.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

*Room mailbox: This is a mailbox to be assigned specifically to Meeting Rooms. 
Its associated user account will be disabled in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string str = "Set-Mailbox -Identity '" + MeetingRoomName + "' -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom " + strUser;
```

Should result in the following be passed to PowerShell for execution:

```
Set-mailbox -identity 'MeetingRoom@domain.com' -acceptmessagesOnlyFrom a.user@domain.com
```

Which will add "a.user@domain.com" to the acceptmessageonlyfrom list of MeetingRoom@domain.com

I'll test this evening when I have access to an Exchange server but this should work.

***Update***
Tested this, I can now confirm the about string/cmdlet successfully adds a user to the acceptmessageOnlyFrom list.

regard
Arcass

Comment: Thank you your reply. The above command 
str = "Set-Mailbox -Identity '" + MeetingRoomName + "' -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom " + strUser;
 will reset and add a user to AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom list. I want to append a user to AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom list.
 I got the this command 
 "Set-Mailbox -Identity 'MeetingRoomName' -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom ((Get-Mailbox -identity 'MeetingRoomName').AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom + 'strUser' )" 
from some site and it is working fine from powershell , but is not working from c# code. please help me to execute this.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do. Will have a play this evening :)

Comment: I got some other solution to do this , but surely not with powershell. we can use AD attribute "authorig" corresponding for AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom. here is the code  public void AddDeliveryRestrictions(string userDn, string allowedUser)
    {
                   DirectoryEntry e= new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + userDn);
            e.Properties["authorig"].AddRange(new object[] { allowedUSer });
            e.CommitChanges();
            }   I found this is easy than powershell